# Mono TypeLoadException on XmlPreloadedResolver

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm working on porting a Windows console app over to Linux using Mono. On my dev machine (Ubuntu), the app works like a charm, but when I try it on my test machine (a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 desktop install) I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Xml.Resolvers.XmlPreloadedResolver' from assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

The only thing I've done to "prep" the test machine is run `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. When I run `dpkg --list | grep mono-system-xml` on the test machine I see this:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep mono-system-xml
ii  libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil                              3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1                               all          Mono System.Xml.Linq library (for CLI 4.0)
ii  libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil                     3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1                               all          Mono System.Xml.Serialization library (for CLI 4.0)
ii  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
```

whereas on my dev machine I see this:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep mono-system-xml
ii  libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil                              4.2.1.102-0xamarin1                                 all          Mono System.Xml.Linq library (for CLI 4.0)
ii  libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil                     4.2.1.102-0xamarin1                                 all          Mono System.Xml.Serialization library (for CLI 4.0)
ii  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil                                   4.2.1.102-0xamarin1                                 all          Mono System.Xml library (for CLI 4.0)
```

I don't know for sure that that version mismatch is the root problem, but it's all I've got to go on for now. I tried installing monodevelop on the test machine via `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`, and I tried upgrading from the xamarin servers by running

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

to no avail. Is there a way to tell where that 4.2.1 version on my dev machine came from? And assuming that's the difference, why would this module be broken in the standard distribution? From the [mono docs](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.XML) it's been implemented and stable for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out this was basically just an order of operations problem.

I had installed `mono-complete` before adding the Xamarin feed, so I got the old broken 3.8 version of Mono that shipped with Ubuntu 14 instead of the latest and greatest. For whatever reason, adding the feed afterwards and doing an `apt-get upgrade` doesn't pick up the updated versions, so you either have to start clean and do things in the right order, or add the feed, look at the output from `apt-cache showpkg mono-complete` to determine the version you really want, and then specify it like `sudo apt-get install mono-complete=4.2.2.30-0xamarin2`.